# The .then() is not working the promise is throwing error but when i remove the for loop it starts working! why?

Tags: node.js

Code snippet:

```
  const User = require('../models/leaderboard').leaderboard;
    const route = require('express').Router();
    const { ensureAuthenticated, forwardAuthenticated } = require('../config/auth');
    route.get('/leaderboard', (req, res) => {
      // We want to send an array a json format of all collectors
      // From our database here
      User.findAll({ order: [['user_id', 'DESC']] })
        .then((leaderboard) => {
          let total_waste = user[0].weight;
          let i = 0,
            j = 1;
          while (i <= user.length - 1) {
            while (j <= user.length) {
              if (user[i].user_id == user[j].user_id) {
                total_waste = total_waste + user[j].weight;
                i++;
                j++;
              } else {
                i = j;
                j = j + 1;
                total_waste = user[i].weight;
              }
            }
          }
          res.send(total_waste);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          res.status(500).send({
            error: 'Could not retrive data',
            err,
          });
        });
    });
    
    exports = module.exports = route;
```

Help me out!

Every time I call this api, I get the error

> Couldn't retrieve data

I am trying to manipulate the data and then send it.

Is it not possible to write a for loop in the router or sequelize `findall` function or some human error I am doing?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from `err` (`console.log` it if you have to)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1:**
You are not actually processing any data because you don't do anything with the data returned by `User.findAll()` and assigned to `leaderboard`. Assuming your user array is what `leaderboard` is referring to, try this:

```js
User.findAll({ order: [['user_id', 'DESC']] })
  .then(leaderboard => {
    let user = leaderboard // assign leaderboard array to 'user' var
    let total_waste = user[0].weight;
    // etc...
```

Or you could just do:

```js
User.findAll({ order: [['user_id', 'DESC']] })
  .then(user => {
    let total_waste = user[0].weight;
    // etc...
```

**Problem 2:**

Your `while` loop will always fail because the last value for `j` is always longer than the array you are processing. Use a `for` loop instead:

```js
User.findAll({ order: [['user_id', 'DESC']] })
.then( user => {
  let total_waste = user[0].weight;
  for (let i = 0; i < (user.length); i++) {
    let j = i + 1;
    if (user[j]) {
      if ( user[i].user_id == user[j].user_id) {
        total_waste = total_waste + user[j].weight;
      } else {
        total_waste = user[i].weight;
      }
    } else {
      // total waste remains the same for the last user
    }
  }
  res.send(total_waste)
})
```

Comment: i mssed to type it here.. after this also I am getting the same error {
    "error": "Could not retrive data",
    "err": {}
}

Comment: you are returning this error in your own code. The actual error object is empty, which is a bit strange.

Comment: Actually @NitinKaushal I just realised where the problem is - your `while` loop will always fail. See updated answer (problem 2)